# POST request executing 6 times instead of one when clicking send button

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, events

I am developing a process which involves multiple forms. The idea is that whenever you click the send button of any form, after checking all the inputs have been filled, my js will hide the already completed form in order to show the new one.

The issue is that whenever I click send, the request launches six times inserting the same data over and over. There is no loop involved in the code, so my guess is that this has something to do with this listener:

`contactForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {`

located here:

```js
var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(contactForm, function(form) {
      contactForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (contactForm.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
```

I am not sure however, since I've later tried to make some changes to no avail.

In any case, this is the code I started with:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var contactForm = document.getElementById('contactForm');
    var customerForm = document.getElementById('customerForm');

    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(contactForm, function(form) {
      contactForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (contactForm.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        contactForm.classList.add('was-validated');

        if (contactForm.checkValidity() === true) {
            customerForm.style.display = 'block';
            contactForm.style.display = 'none';
            event.preventDefault();
            (function() {
                var contactEmail = document.getElementById('contactEmail').value;
                var contactResellerId = 2;
                var contactName = document.getElementById('contactName').value;
                var contactLastName = document.getElementById('contactLastName').value;
                var contactCompany =  document.getElementById('contactCompany').value;
                var contactRegNum = document.getElementById('contactRegNum').value;

                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    method: 'POST',
                    crossDomain: true,
                    withCredentials: true,
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        firstname: contactName,
                        lastname: contactLastName,
                        company: contactCompany,
                        email: contactEmail,
                        reseller_id: contactResellerId,
                        comregnum: contactRegNum
                    }),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': 'Basic '+token,
                    }
                })
                .done(function (response) { alert('Se ha creado el contacto!'); })
                .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(jqXHR); });
            })();
        }
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
```

And this is what I have right now:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var contactForm = document.getElementById('contactForm');
    var customerForm = document.getElementById('customerForm');
    var submitContact = document.getElementById('submitContact');

    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(contactForm, function(form) {
      submitContact.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        if (contactForm.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        contactForm.classList.add('was-validated');

        if (contactForm.checkValidity() === true) {
                event.preventDefault();
                customerForm.style.display = 'block';
                contactForm.style.display = 'none';
                (function() {
                        var contactEmail = document.getElementById('contactEmail').value;
                        var contactResellerId = 2;
                        var contactName = document.getElementById('contactName').value;
                        var contactLastName = document.getElementById('contactLastName').value;
                        var contactCompany =  document.getElementById('contactCompany').value;
                        var contactRegNum = document.getElementById('contactRegNum').value;

                        $.ajax({
                                url: url,
                                method: 'POST',
                                crossDomain: true,
                                withCredentials: true,
                                data: JSON.stringify({
                                        firstname: contactName,
                                        lastname: contactLastName,
                                        company: contactCompany,
                                        email: contactEmail,
                                        reseller_id: contactResellerId,
                                        comregnum: contactRegNum
                                }),
                                dataType: 'json',
                                contentType: 'application/json',
                                headers: {
                                        'Authorization': 'Basic '+token,
                                }
                        })
                        .done(function (response) { alert('Se ha creado el contacto!'); })
                        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log(jqXHR); });
                })();
        }
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
```

This is the form this is getting the info from:

```html
<form class="needs-validation provisioningForm" id="contactForm" novalidate>
        <h2 class="title">Crear Contacto</h2>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
              <label for="contactName">Nombre</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contactName" required>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Debes introducir el nombre del contacto.
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
              <label for="contactLastName">Apellidos</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contactLastName" required>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Debes introducir los apellidos del contacto.
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-12 mb-4">
              <label for="contactEmail">Email</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                  <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupPrepend">@</span>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contactEmail" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend" required>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Debes introducir un correo válido.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
              <label for="contactCompany">Empresa</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contactCompany" required>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Debes introducir el nombre de la empresa.
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
              <label for="contactRegNum">C.I.F.</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contactRegNum" required>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Debes incluir el CIF de la empresa.
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button id="submitContact" class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Enviar</button>
    </form>
```

A few notes:

1. Everything is working fine. There are no warnings/errors displayed on console. The issue lies in the fact that the POST request is executing 6 times.
2. There are 5 forms with 5 submit buttons and a total of 5 functions. All have different id's. As I was saying in the beginning, I believe the cause to be the event listener placed on the `'submit'`. I think that since the other forms are just hidden, but there, it may be taking the other submits. But after trying to store them in separate variables and to place a `.click` listener on them and still get the same result I am even more confused.

If you need any extra info I'll post it right away. Thank you all for your time and help.

Comment: Could you explain why the `Array.prototype.filter.call`? Are you trying to loop over something?

Comment: What is the purpose of your `Array.prototype.filter.call`? You're calling it on an element, not an array-like object, and you're not using the iterative `form` that's passed to the callback. At the moment it seems needless.

Comment: Hi all! Thaks for the reply, there are some pieces of code I got from the web, that is one of them. It was supposedly part of a function which controlled the form, making sure that all the fields are filled. I started working on that. Could that be the cause of this issue? How could I maintain the functionality while getting rid of the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you may be adding multiple "submit" events as you surmised. This line appears to be unnecessary:

```
var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(contactForm, function(form) {
```

If you remove it (and the closing `}`), your submit event should be added only once, on window.load.

Comment: Hi Ed! Thanks for the answer and explanation. This worked perfectly fine! I got that code from bootstrap's page, I should have investigated a little bit what it actually meant and did before throwing it into my own code. I'll be more carefull the next time :)

Comment: I just re-read your question. Since you have multiple forms, you can give them a common class (e.g. contactForm), select them all with `document.querySelector('.contactForm')`, loop over that and target individual buttons to add the submission/validation code.

Comment: Oh that is just great!! I am quite new to JS and I thought this project would be a nice way to start, so I dont' know a lot of features and functions. Thank you again for the tip!